# CakePHP containable behavior doesn't work well within tests

Tags: cakephp

Using CakePHP v2.6.2, I'm trying to test models using containable behavior
running with command.

```
./Console/cake test app
```

The models work well on web app but doesn't work within the test.

I have a class Foo with two hasOne entry. User and User2 represents same table.

```
class Foo extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = [
        'User' => [
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'foo_id',
        ],
        'User2' => [
            'className' => 'User2',
            'foreignKey' => 'foo_id',
        ],
    ];
}
class User extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'users';
}
class User2 extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'users';
}
```

Then, use it.

```
$this->Foo->find('first', [
    'contain' => ['User','User2'],
    'recursive' => -1,
]);
```

Inside a CakeTestCase subclasses, it fails to join User2.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `skr011`.`ne_foos` AS `Foo`
    LEFT JOIN `skr011`.`ne_users` AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `Foo`.`id`)
```

On the real usecase on web app, it works well.

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    `skr011`.`ne_foos` AS `Foo`
    LEFT JOIN `skr011`.`ne_users` AS `User` ON (`User`.`id` = `Foo`.`id`)
    LEFT JOIN `skr011`.`ne_users` AS `User2` ON (`User2`.`id` = `Foo`.`id`)
```

It seems to occure when and only when a table is appears twice in the sql,
not sure though.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Thanks.

[Edit]

Fixed the code above that forignKeys have been wrong derection.
And More realistic example is bellow.

```
class Article extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = [
        'Comment' => [
            'className' => 'Comment',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        ],
    ];
    public $hasOne = [
        'CommentLatest' => [
            'className' => 'CommentLatest',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'conditions' => 'CommentLatest.latest_flag = 1',
        ],
        'CommentMostPopular' => [
            'className' => 'CommentMostPopular',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
            'conditions' => 'CommentMostPopular.most_popular_flag = 1',
        ],
    ];
}
class Comment extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = [
        'Article' => [
            'className' => 'Article',
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Usage.

```
$this->Article->find('first', [
    'contain' => ['CommentLatest', 'CommentMostPopular'],
]);
```

[Edit]

It works fine in own command shells. It seems to occure only in tests.

Comment: Have you got public $useTable = "users"; In your User2 model?

Comment: Oh I've forgotten about $useTable. Neither classes explicitly implemented the variable. I'll try, thanks. However, to tell the truth, I don't want to implement User2 class but just do 'User2' => ['className' => 'User', 'foreignKey' => 'user_id']. This also works for web but doesn't for tests.

Comment: So your Foo entity can haveMany User entities? In which case set it up so Foo hasMany User and User belongsTo Foo, then include foo_id in your users table as the foreign key. Cake's ORM will produce something like:  SELECT * FROM 'foos' AS 'Foo' LEFT JOIN 'users' AS 'User' ON ('Foo.id' = 'User.foo_id')  returning all the User records which belong to the given Foo record. I think that's what you are trying to do?

Comment: Did you load all the necessary fixtures so all the tables that need to be joined together actually exist in your test db?

Comment: @SimonMason Sorry my code was too artificial so I might mistaken something. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Oldskool I don't use fixtures and the DB is shared with web app. Is this possibly be a proplem?

Comment: You should always use fixtures to ensure that the tests don't interfere with the live data, and also to ensure that the data will always remain the same every time the tests are run. What version of cake are you using, and what is the error message you are getting in the console?

Comment: @SimonMason $useTable didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mcgowan.b My tests always start with schema create command so the result always same. The version is v2.6.2 (I upgraded it for this topic). There is no error message. I slso found that the same find() within own console/commands work fine so it occures only inside the tests.

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark, but if you set debug to 0, then clear all the tmp/cache folders do you still get different results in production to test?

Comment: If you're creating schema when you run your tests, what are you populating the tables with? That's what a fixture will do for you, and you can specify that data that goes in every time

Comment: Hmmm, I might have had a misconception about something. The find result is always right but the getDataSource()->getLog() is wrong within tests? I should chage the debug method first.

Comment: @Simon Mason Thanks, checking debug mode was helpful.

Comment: @mcgowan.b Thanks. My tests starts with SQL dump insertion or empty. I decided doing so years ago but I might be wrong :).

Comment: I'm so sorry everyone. I found my fault. Only on the tests, within the same process, I've done $model = new $modelname() before ClassRegistry::init which might haven't propery initialized the model (maybe only with some conditions of model relations). Just getting rid of raw new and using ClassRegistry::init solved the problem. Thank you.